# Not able to run alsamixer in Fedora 25 as Root User

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I have been trying for a very long time to run alsamixer. Here 's the output upon writing alsamixer in the terminal in Fedora 25. I am running as root user because whenever I open alsamixer as just user, there is just one Master Control although I have my speakers plugged in like so[image]

And the output on running `alsamixer -c 0`

[image]

```
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by
uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root 
PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:   
Connection refused

cannot open mixer: Connection refused
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to Pulseaudio (because of the Pulseaudio layer that allows legacy ALSA clients) as root, which was started as user 1000 (whatever the name is), and that doesn't work. Why not run `alsamixer` as user?

Comment: You could try `alsamixer -c 0` to show the controls of the first hardware device, but those are not the PulseAudio controls.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the master control because you have not selected a soundcard, and the default Pulseaudio compatibility layer just has this one control. That has nothing to do with being root or non-root.

So run `alsamixer` as user. Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select the soundcard you have connected your speakers to, and <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> to switch between capture and playback controls.

Or use `aplay -l` to see your cards, and `alsamixer -c card_number`.

If you are running Pulseaudio anyway, I'd advise to leave the the mixer controls alone (unless something is not working), and use `pavucontrol` to set the volume. This will use the ALSA mixer controls if necessary.

Comment: I tried both of them in case of the first method you mention I get this output: `cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument`                                  And in the second case I get this output: `ALSA lib simple_none.c:1549:(simple_add1) helem (MIXER,'Master Playback Switch',0,1,0) appears twice or more
cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument`                                                   And `pavucontrol` display only the dummy output.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`. If you have made a custom `~/.asoundrc`, please also include it in the question. Finally, for all the card numbers you can see, do `amixer -c0 controls`, `amixer -c1 controls` etc., and see if it works. To verify Pulseaudio finds all cards, include the output of `pacmd list-sinks | grep name:`.